# How to properly style custom bootstrap form validation

Tags: javascript, bootstrapvalidator

I have created a custom validation check for bootstrap form validator (it's the else part below) :

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
        }
        else if (myConditionIsNotMet()) {
            form.querySelector("#myInputField").classList.add('is-invalid');
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
})
```

The targeted input field already has a "required" attribute that works fine.

Using the above code, I have managed to make the validation error message appear and stop the form submission, but the outline of the field is green instead of red.

[image]

It seems my element ends up with both the *is-valid* and *is-invalid* classes due to the "required" validation.

[image]

I read in another post that there's an updateStatus function that can set a field as invalid. It seems that's what I need, but I haven't figured out how to access it via my form element.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a noob when it comes to javascript :\

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is NOT the optimal solution, but I managed to get what I wanted with this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (myConditionIsNotMet()) {
            form.querySelector("#myInputField").setCustomValidity("Oops!");
        }
        else {
            form.querySelector("#myInputField").setCustomValidity("");
        }
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
})
```